# List of applications that give for port-forwarding capabilities

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I know that command line tools like `ssh` or `netcat` or something like `PAT` will allow you to forward ports. But surely there's more. I wanted to know of more applications that give port-forwarding capabilities, so I could try and use them and see differences, if any.

Additionally, are there any "industry standards" for port forwarding? SSH seems to be the only one that comes up when I Google anything about this topic.

Comment: Having multiple tools to compare with each other let's me understand the task they accomplish more fluidly. (As well as judge which one I like the most)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- socat
- haproxy
- proxies (SOCKS)
- stunnel (special case, of course)